# Creating a todo list app and stuck on post

Tags: javascript, express, post

I don't want the answer but rather a point in the right direction as this is for my final exam or a starting point as well. This is what is giving and I just need to fill in the rest. Also we cant use local storage to save user input

```
// POST handler adds a task to a list
app.post('/task', (req, res) => {
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

/*
    Input: data coming into this handler will be in the form:

    {"task": "mytask"}

    You can see contents of the incoming request with:
    console.log(req.body.task). "req" is the request
    and within it, the property req.body holds the incoming data
    above from the client request, hence "task" is a property of
    that incoming request data object.

    Output: This handler should send the datastore back to
    the client with a 201 response code if successful, and return
    and 400 response code with no response body if the task already
    exists in either the TODO or Completed list.
*/


console.log(req.body.task);

/*
    YOUR CODE HERE
*/

// send 201 status with no response body
res.status(201).send({})
});
```

I have several tabs open with different articles on node and post, but maybe its just not me getting the concept.

Here is what i have for datastore

```
let taskDatastore = {
"todo": [
    "finish test 2",
],
"completed": [
    "read the test instructions",
],
};
```

Comment: What are you struggling with specifically? Also, "This handler should send the datastore back to the client" doesn't tell us much. What is your datastore in this case?

Comment: @NickParsons   Sorry adding more info to the post. I think it just filling in the rest of the code to what the comments say. I feel like it's simple but it just not coming to me.

Comment: No worries. Do you understand what the `app.post('/task', (req, res) => {` is doing and what a POST request is? Or do you mainly need assistance with checking the datastore and sending back a reply?

Comment: @NickParsons    If I'm understanding it correctly, it's requesting to accept the input and storing it?

Comment: If `req.body.task` prints the POST'd object containing the new task, then perhaps you might consider gathering up the task up from the `req`, adding it to the `"todo"` array, and sending back the `taskDataStore`

Comment: @Strife_x7x - This: "_This handler should send the datastore back to
    the client with a 201 response_" is pretty clear about sending the datastore "_back to the client_" right? That doesn't mean store it - it means send it back. The starter code even provides the way to do that at the very bottom.

Comment: @Strife_x7x to me it doesn't seem like the task is asking you to add the task to your datastore (Maybe you have another endpoint responsible for doing that?). What I think they want you to do is loop through the `todo` array & `completed` array, & check whether or not `req.body.task` exists within any of arrays (you can use `.includes()` if you don't want to write a for loop). If it does, then you can send the `400` reply back, & if it doesn't send the datastore to the client using a 201 response. Whether you need to add the actual task to the datastore before you send it back isn't specified

Answer (score 0):

First extract the ***task*** from the request body, Then check if the ***todo*** or ***completed*** arrays contain this task and send the respective status codes in the response.

```js
// POST handler adds a task to a list
app.post('/task', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

  /*
      Input: data coming into this handler will be in the form:

      {"task": "mytask"}

      You can see contents of the incoming request with:
      console.log(req.body.task). "req" is the request
      and within it, the property req.body holds the incoming data
      above from the client request, hence "task" is a property of
      that incoming request data object.

      Output: This handler should send the datastore back to
      the client with a 201 response code if successful, and return
      and 400 response code with no response body if the task already
      exists in either the TODO or Completed list.
  */


  let taskDatastore = {
    "todo": [
      "finish test 2",
    ],
    "completed": [
      "read the test instructions",
    ],
  };

  const task = req.body.task;

  // Check if task already exists in the TODO or COMPLETED arrays
  if (taskDatastore.todo.includes(task) || taskDatastore.completed.includes(task)) {
    // send 400 status with no response body
    res.status(400).send({});
  } else {
    // send 201 status with datastore in response body
    res.status(201).send(taskDatastore);
  }
});
```